# PostGIS: type "raster" does not exist

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, ubuntu, raster2pgsql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and PostGIS.

I'm adding a raster to a newly created PostGIS schema and table with the raster2pgsql command:

```
sudo raster2pgsql -I -C -s 3577 -t 50x60 /path/to/raster.tif schema.table | sudo -u user psql dbname 

Processing 1/1: ./sat/geotiff_clum_50m1218m/clum_50m1218m.tif
BEGIN
ERROR:  type "raster" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ata"."lulc_raster" ("rid" serial PRIMARY KEY,"rast" raster);
```

Found some helpful info about making sure that the PostGIS extension was enabled on my schema and can confirm that they are:

```
create extension postgis;
extension "postgis" already exists

create extension postgis_raster;
extension "postgis_raster" already exists
```

And that the raster type exists in the schema:

[image]

Using PostGIS 3.1 and PostgreSQL 13, on Ubuntu 20.04.
I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 7):

For me the answer was: run `create extension postgis_raster` from a SQL client.

I had never used this extension, only vanilla `postgis`, but I was trying to install a PostGIS "add-on" that expected `postgis_raster`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that the extensions postgis and postgis_raster were in the wrong schema: the extensions were in the postgis schema not my newly created schema. The other issue was that the search path was not pointing to the newly created schema.

```
#to see which schema an extension is installed into: 
\dx (from the psql prompt)

# to change the extension schema
ALTER EXTENSION ext_name SET SCHEMA myschema; 


#This changes the search path to the right schema
ALTER USER username SET search_path TO schemaname, "$user", public, postgis_schema;
```